# Proving the equivalence of the properties of onto functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I have problem showing (3)=>(1).
I know that to show a function is surjective, first take a random y from the function's range and then represent x in terms of y and show that x is in the function's domain but I cannot figure out how I could use (3) to show (1).

Answer (score 3):

Take $y\in Y$. Our goal is to prove that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is non-empty. If it is empty, then, we see that
$$f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \varnothing = f^{-1}(\varnothing)$$
so, $(3)$ would implies that $\{y\} = \varnothing$, a contradiction. Therefore, $f^{-1}(\{y\}) \neq \varnothing$ and hence, there exists some $x\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$, that is, there exists some $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $f^{-1}(f(X)) = f^{-1}(Y)$ for any function, and so (3) implies that $f(X)=Y$.